# In C how is it determined if two types are identical?

Tags: c++, c

From

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.vacpp7a.doc/language/ref/clrc03compatible_types.htm

***The presence of type specifiers in various combinations for arithmetic types may or may not     indicate different types. For example, the type signed int is the same as int, except when used as the types of bit fields; but char, signed char, and unsigned char are different types.***

What is the reason for this difference between int and char with respect to type identity ?

I guess the same rules apply in C++ as well. Hence adding the c++ tag as well to this question

Comment: Do you want to know how to tell if types or identical, or why is the signedness of `char` different?  Those are different questions.

Comment: Historically - before there was the language standard - `char` was signed on some systems, unsigned on others. This behavior is standardized, for backward compatibility: it's implementation-defined whether `char` is signed or unsigned. On the other hand, `int` was always treated as signed everywhere, so no such shenanigans are necessary.

Comment: The fact that `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` are different types is the same in both languages, but equality of types means a thousand times more in C++ than in C.

Comment: @aschepler Can you point to some info on the differences between C & C++ in determining type equality ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Originally C did not have `unsigned` types, so `char` was signed by default. Since the PDP-11 used 8-bit bytes and an ASCII character set, `char` objects were [not expected to take negative values](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/cman.pdf):

> Characters (declared, and hereinafter called, `char`) are chosen from the ASCII set; they occupy the right-most seven bits of an 8-bit byte. It is also possible to interpret `char`s as signed, 2’s complement 8-bit
>   numbers.

`unsigned` types were [added around 1977](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/chist.html) partially to discourage the use of pointers for unsigned arithmetic:

> [...] the similarity of the arithmetic properties of character pointers and unsigned integers made it hard to resist the temptation to identify them. The unsigned types were added to make unsigned arithmetic available without confusing it with pointer manipulation.

The problem with making `char` signed is that in order to perform arithmetic on `char` values it is necessary to [sign-extend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension) them. This was efficient on PDP-11, which had an SXT instruction, but [not on ARM](http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/portability-the-arm-processor/184405435) (at least, not until version 4 of the ARM architecture was released in 1996):

> [...] you'll find no single "load character from memory and sign extend" in the ARM instruction set. That's why, for performance reasons, every compiler I'm aware of makes the default char type signed on x86, but unsigned on ARM. [...]

Thus when C was standardized the committee had the choice of either making `char` signed - and thus forcing ARM implementations to change to become inefficient - or reflecting existing practice and making the signedness of `char` implementation-defined.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the early _C Reference Manual_ link.  Interesting to note `end-of-file ( ´\0´ returned from "getchar" )"`, so `EOF` was 0, BITD.

Comment: Thanks. ARM didn't have a sign extended load only for characters but had such an instruction for short (16 bit words) ?

Comment: @Santhosh in the original architecture, LDR could handle word (32-bit) and unsigned byte loads: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0068b/Bcfihdhj.html Halfword and signed byte loads were introduced together in ARM architecture v4: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0068b/Chdbifed.html

Answer (score 3):

From C++11: (snippets from various paragraphs in § 3.9)

> Plain char, signed char, and unsigned char are three distinct types, collectively called narrow character types.
>
> There are five standard signed integer types : “signed char”, “short int”, “int”, “long int”, and “long long int”.
>   For each of the standard signed integer types, there exists a corresponding (but different) standard unsigned
>
> integer type: “unsigned char”, “unsigned short int”, “unsigned int”, “unsigned long int”,
>   and “unsigned long long int”, each of which occupies the same amount of storage and has the same
>   alignment requirements (3.11) as the corresponding signed integer type47;
>
> Type wchar_t is a distinct type...Types char16_t and char32_t denote distinct types...
>
> Values of type bool are either true or false.49 [ Note: There are no signed, unsigned, short, or long
>   bool types or values. —end note ]

§ 7.1.6.2 lists a table of which keywords result in which types:

```
type-name          the type named
simple-template-id the type as defined in 14.2
char               “char”
unsigned char      “unsigned char”
signed char        “signed char”
char16_t           “char16_t”
char32_t           “char32_t”
bool               “bool”
unsigned           “unsigned int”
unsigned int       “unsigned int”
signed             “int”
signed int         “int”
int                “int”
unsigned short int “unsigned short int”
unsigned short     “unsigned short int”
unsigned long int  “unsigned long int”
unsigned long      “unsigned long int”
unsigned long long int “unsigned long long int”
unsigned long long “unsigned long long int”
signed long int    “long int”
signed long        “long int”
signed long long int “long long int”
signed long long   “long long int”
long long int      “long long int”
long long          “long long int”
long int           “long int”
long               “long int”
signed short int   “short int”
signed short       “short int”
short int          “short int”
short              “short int”
wchar_t            “wchar_t”
float              “float”
double             “double”
long double        “long double”
void               “void”
auto               placeholder for a type to be deduced
decltype(expression) the type as defined below
```

As for why `char` is wierd, I'm told that origionally, there was some compiler that made `char` unsigned (before `unsigned` types were conceived of?).  The C++ standard wanted to rectify this, but didn't want to break existing code, so they made the signedness of `char` implementation defined, and added `signed char` as a separate type.

Comment: You may want to address how qualifiers: `const`, `volatile`, `restrict` affect or do not affect types.

Comment: @chux: I can't think of a short way to accurately describe `const` and `volatile` because it's a lot of sometimes yes and sometimes no.  I'm not familiar with `restrict` at all.